# EntityFramework 7 with MVC 6 API - InvalidOperationError

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Am struggling with configuring a basic EntityFramework7-powered API app... I'm following this tutorial :
http://aspnetmvc.readthedocs.io/projects/mvc/en/1.0.0-beta7/tutorials/mvc-with-entity-framework.html

I've got Book and Author models, BookContext, my connectionString in AppSettings.json. The ConfigureService method in startup.cs is set. I build the solution and I've run `dnu restore` a billion times.

I had to add `EntityFramework.Commands` to the dependencies list 'cause when I ran `dnx ef` I had this error :

> dnx : Error: Unable to load application or execute command 'EntityFramework.Commands'. 
>   Available commands: web, ef.

Now all I've got when I type in `dnx ef` is this

> dnx : System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 
>   'Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.IApplicationEnvironment' has been registered.

My dnvm version : `1.0.0-rc1-update2 clr  x86   win`

dependencies in project.json :

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet": "1.0.0-rc1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

Startup.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;
using TestEf.Models;

namespace TestEf
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            // Set up configuration sources.
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

            if (env.IsEnvironment("Development"))
            {
                // This will push telemetry data through Application Insights pipeline faster, allowing you to view results immediately.
                builder.AddApplicationInsightsSettings(developerMode: true);
            }

            builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build().ReloadOnChanged("appsettings.json");
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddEntityFramework()
                .AddSqlServer()
                .AddDbContext<BookContext>(options =>
                {
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.Get("Data:ConnectionString"));
                });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

            app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();

            app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc();
        }

        // Entry point for the application.
        public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
    }
}
```

BookContext.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;

namespace TestEf.Models
{
    public class BookContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    }
}
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Verbose",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },


  "AppSettings": {
    "SiteTitle": "Contoso Books"
  },
  "Data": {
    "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=ContosoBooks;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to run `dnu rebuild` in directory where the `project.json` is located?